# JVM should have exited but did not

Tags: java, jvm, jmeter

While executing script using JMeter in non gui mode i'm getting error message described below when Thread group count is 100 and ramp up period is 60 sec

```
Tidying up ...    
The JVM should have exitted but did not.
The following non-daemon threads are still running (DestroyJavaVM is OK):
Thread[StandardJMeterEngine,5,main], stackTrace:sun.nio.fs.WindowsNativeDispatcher#CopyFileEx0
sun.nio.fs.WindowsNativeDispatcher#CopyFileEx
sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy#copy
sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider#copy
java.nio.file.Files#copy
org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.TemplateVisitor#visitFile at line:126
org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.TemplateVisitor#visitFile at line:48
java.nio.file.Files#walkFileTree
java.nio.file.Files#walkFileTree
org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.HtmlTemplateExporter#export at line:487
org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.ReportGenerator#exportData at line:348
org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.ReportGenerator#generate at line:256
org.apache.jmeter.JMeter$ListenToTest#generateReport at line:1144
org.apache.jmeter.JMeter$ListenToTest#testEnded at line:1089
org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine#notifyTestListenersOfEnd at line:215
org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine#run at line:436
java.lang.Thread#run

Thread[DestroyJavaVM,5,main], stackTrace:
... end of run
```

How to resolve this error? what exactly this error means? How to handle this error?

Comment: https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/issues/24

Comment: Any feedback on answer ? if ok it should be accepted and upvoted so that users know it is usable. Thx

Comment: Try jmeterengine.force.system.exit=true.  This question is duplicate. I've added my answer (seen with JMeter 5.1) to the duplicate question here: stackoverflow.com/a/59976286

Comment: Try jmeterengine.force.system.exit=true. This question is duplicate. I've added my answer to the duplicate question here: stackoverflow.com/a/59976286

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug fixed in jmeter 3.1 (to be released soon):

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60053

Report generation is in progress while you have this message.

Wait for it to be generated and kill the jvm instance:

> kill pid